# How do I change the year?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm copying and pasting things over from an old spreadsheet and the original dates where marked like '25/4' so dd/mm but I never included the year.

The problem is these where dated in 2014 but when I'm pasting them over the spreadsheet is automatically dating them in 2015. I do NOT want this.

Is there a way to prevent them from either adding on the year or to change the year?

Answer (score 4):

In Google Spreadsheets, a date always refers to some year, although the year need not be shown. Otherwise it's not a date but a string. A string is stored as is, but you can't do any computations with it, and sorting will be alphabetical rather than chronological.

#### If you prefer to keep 25/4 as a string

Prior to posting data, format the column for the date as plain text. (From the menu: Format > Number > Plain Text).

#### If you prefer to have dates, but change the year to 2014

Suppose your current dates, with 2015, are in column A. Create another column with the formula `=A2-365` (in the second row), etc. This column will have the dates in 2014. Copy its contents and paste as *values* (Ctrl-Shift-V) back to column A.

#### If you just want to hide the year

Format the dates so that the year is not shown. From the menu: Format > Number > More formats > More date and time formats... and pick or create a format you prefer.